# Compile L20n to es5

Tags: babeljs, rollupjs, l20n

L20n is compiled to es2015 which is not supported by IE11.
I want to compile L20n to es5. i used babel-preset-es2015-ie but this led to problems with external-helpers.

The existing .babelrc is

```
"presets": [
    ["latest", {
        "es2015": {
            "modules": false
        }
     }]
],
"plugins": [
    "external-helpers",
    ["babel-plugin-transform-builtin-extend", { globals: ["Error"] }]
]
```

My question is how to change the existing .Babelrc to compile to es5 and not break rollup or add a polyfill that will make it work on IE11.